# Spring Security Win Auth example is not authenticating properly - says null keytab file when it is clearly being passed in and acknowledged

Tags: spring, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I have downloaded and tried testing the sec-server-win-auth sample app for Spring Security Extensions.  I performed the following steps:

1. download and build the spring-security-Kerberos-master project.
2. pulled out the sec-server-win-auth-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar into a
   folder on PROD server.
3. create a new application.yml in the same folder with my custom
   information
4. create a tomcat.keytab on my test domain controller, named DC.
5. copy the tomcat.keytab file to my PROD server.
6. run java -jar sec-server-win-auth-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
7. On a separate client,CLIENT1, open IE and go to http://PROD:8080/

At this point, I see the request for the Kerberos negotiate header and the response with the header.  It says it is valid and it tries to authenticate it, but I get the following error. "unable to obtain password from user"

This error is coming from the Krb5LoginModule.  There is a hint to the issue above this error that says the key for the principal is not available in the keytab file.  The principal is available, it is just getting null for my keytab file.

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null     refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAI
N.LOCAL tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false  clearPass is false
Key for the principal HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL not available in default key tab
                [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed
Unable to obtain password from user
```

If I look further up in the logging stream, I can see that the keytab file is being passed in correctly from the application.yml and being loaded.

```
useKeyTab=true, keyTab=c:/kerberos/tomcat.keytab, debug=true, doNotPrompt=true}
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is c:/kerberos/tomcat.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP
/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded
```

I am not sure why my keytab is coming through as null further down the line.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
INFO 4564 --- [           main] demo.app.Application                     : Starting Application v1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on PROD with PID 4564 (C:\kerberos\sec-server-win-auth-1.
0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar started by tc01 in c:\kerberos)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5
6459b78: startup date [Fri Mar 27 23 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scop
e=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$White
labelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/Error
MvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=
false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName
=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [c
lass org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c6bd8b6a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example:
not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Annotati
onTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.Transaction
Interceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springfr
amework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
INFO 4564 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2543 ms
WARN 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.e.k.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator : Initial Keytab location is:file:/c:/kerberos/tomcat.keytab
WARN 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.e.k.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator : Your keytab starts with file:.  Stripping it from path for Java 7 compatibility. TP
WARN 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.e.k.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator : Loading Keytab file from the following path: c:/kerberos/tomcat.keytab
WARN 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.e.k.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator : loginConfig data is:{isInitiator=false, storeKey=true, principal=HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL,
useKeyTab=true, keyTab=c:/kerberos/tomcat.keytab, debug=true, doNotPrompt=true}
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is c:/kerberos/tomcat.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP
/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded

INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.e.k.c.KerberosLdapContextSource    :  URL 'ldap://DC.DOMAIN.LOCAL/', root DN is ''
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : AuthenticationSource not set - using default implementation
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Using LDAP pooling.
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Trying provider Urls: ldap://DC.DOMAIN.LOCAL/
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation
.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@4f38d17a
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation
.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@1b40c938
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation
.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@3a5a8982
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for org.springframework.security.config.annotation
.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport$ExactUrlRequestMatcher@cbbe2cf
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/']
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/home']
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for org.springframework.security.web.util.matc
her.AnyRequestMatcher@1
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.sprin
gframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5c5a072a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@71142e50, org.springframework.securit
y.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@709820cd, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@17fdb097, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@653c5652, org.springframework.s
ecurity.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6a5b07f2, org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter@1a8c85c4, org.springframework.securi
ty.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4c3d80e9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@11e86f65, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Anon
ymousAuthenticationFilter@7fa21479, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@40d2c946, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@72b368f3, org.springfr
amework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1ed5eb39]
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter' to: [/*]
INFO 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] k.w.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Initializing filter 'spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] k.w.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Filter 'spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter' configured successfully
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
DEBUG 4564 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured successfully
INFO 4564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWeb
ApplicationContext@56459b78: startup date [Fri Mar 27 23 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO 4564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public or
g.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto
public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Parameteriz
ableViewController]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Parameteriza
bleViewController]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Parameteriz
ableViewController]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewContro
ller]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceH
ttpRequestHandler]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.R
esourceHttpRequestHandler]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resour
ce.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
INFO 4564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
INFO 4564 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 4564 --- [           main] demo.app.Application                     : Started Application in 5.523 seconds (JVM running for 6.365)
INFO 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
INFO 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 32 ms
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFil
ter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFil
ter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web
.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@33baf8cf
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /hello' doesn't match 'POST /logout
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticatio
nFilter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /hello' doesn't match 'POST /login
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /hello at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SpnegoAuthenticationProcessin
gFilter'
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] k.w.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Received Negotiate Header for request http://prod:8080/hello: Negotiate YIIGPwYGKwYBBQUCoIIGMzCCBi+g
MDAuBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCqKCBfkEggX1YIIF8QYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggXgMIIF3KADAgEFoQMCAQ6iBwMFACAAAACjggRkYYIEYDCCBFygAwIBBaEOGwxET01BSU4uTE9DQUyiJDAioAMCAQKhGzAZGwRI
VFRQGxFwcm9kLmRvbWFpbi5sb2NhbKOCBB0wggQZoAMCARehAwIBBqKCBAsEggQHvjMpkhlvwPjCmBCH09gyPQoTR4eydq69R6YizJKFZcN8BmEW0p1lS2So0FGxZflvRALL0Ev2+ME0Jub6QJ3bEDyr2XsRWeDViJbFIM5BDLc0F5qKdIj65Nw/ltB7fr/aWSOwpI/b
a1vQzUeLEnRzBAbkN23r+SETz7Yjgygof3BMr6DjmHWPWtogOchkkqCtz4o5WFXWpbWDKtXLKhV2BzHHE7aMVhGhLokMhn1cP3YI/0k7R/9zoILt53PIaK05MWF3k6mdPSFCkMd+BAkpVEIYQ8sSC/83UtsXU7ndGNfQuq5096nlsx2hP7Mk3qR/vGha2KO82DcEFSB0
lnRNel5wXw3wAfjzp3D2p62a/cnc9/ZqzMBfqjgZbDg9uBT0O41rGgHZX+acRvudcZBk2MQbWg9BSrthSZYDFgoS1gsTDusEsBpQc42mKHRTboMHpTRB9hoF3BD+MJeaTHAj2r0puLNJlATOMtqvFEJ+FQBN1yJikiFhG8OdBpahGAll9oVhThtwVj7M8weygDFDagCj
6lqIMKtpacaDEPmk2dmRNYPi64/tT6lx5fGmcxoL+Z3gIK5+oLlv6EnfR5PT6lKErgzbtuYc+gHMzZuztKNIEqFk6pjeXXnOKDB2P3XOyeP6rbdvnZ5MTJDhlVOsrOjh2giYTgjVj8Z+U0dJlkK0V3XHkz5VVg3IQobdyhxXxbkPBvXqOvaeDB+abQvnq1VIap5P7xGi
G3MUBMFBBVKdyVyGRcYnr6qp458GsOxZ06pGUE8pWiu+1vh3uT9qYSG0JJKULQvZLPEdKyaK2Dck4etgYuLk5odaT2bBDTqW2DA3NKxZpmCicTtHtfyJGMthp74uvpnD0iif+4S94pa7CkPwWv0jk8aOiQ3QHOZ7M2uGix7OCS2KHraVOD7BocqhgksTgAL/VLdKtjSy
saEkp3pSlkDLNnn9DwsYtno7trIDRIF1K0v8N0BdM8D7DS+J2KY7X4xs7giUYSPZjwflyoRruSrhRSnuiEv9RrIpZT6uhIMmz+2QOiKKqQBTiyEo27u+ztCjakX+qencMx6hxr7CogP28fQWNKISI2sRpgEhn7X/eVijqmnuDkBVGTgYkv7nTD6PWP6rhsaMoMvBIKwr
55ga1Tq0RRwpAUHO3+k7bqqsMuqoTouVN9pmP7xFPOwU7nP7oTApypbegtPVsxGrOeADpPcYNX3rxH1mq6N4gs5+BKhHa63ddbFcLbjb2GKcT5VrY4OLjVuCwEO1X5GSQwbhvXXu+lf1SWlc0Uvapu7CyU0fgLFan6jbTUaj4n7k1jz+RyFo2BSg2AWSgVCP3b/13F9b
DqgpEyVDh0507PxH3KNU7eB8pXht1eS9tTghAzGkggFdMIIBWaADAgEXooIBUASCAUy3vlYBZVSaqNUbw7VGO3YQlDV+Iw3+WnAnwcEXkt34PI95jOk3+Z/uHd6h2dAYo2qNHmXwX0S/p4BVnyEak5azsDxPbQKCKS6rzfYQmgSMx9PT9NYKR8rVyEHAjgW2/ajkSS8s
AnDNfsbkmKGKrKukEDAoJ7ij+S5f3HQ6NMeu+pF54ZFQ403Gby/cPFfQ6Jl96p1dsiF3v2p6AB7F5xQV6rd4G5R+cEqK/g77VQV7U0Jfj2qWgTXDwgjHuzuRFzdlNIMp+CBR0uyqH1c2nVugmkZMqwbBXULSQgGIKF6Vfo3WMACThjm0oUV0Xqz2/MCNgD7SfjEVIc7w
xWH+aUjBSGKWcxe+tUsULa0saYBXxI6MKJVM/tuyj6vAXFTTaGFWEJlWaPGe3TVaaCx7u3Dz2ih0SUtaBQlf1kvHwclHUe89BSVLYATXTV5dFA==
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthent
icationProvider
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .k.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider : Try to validate Kerberos Token
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .k.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider : Succesfully validated spectrum@DOMAIN.LOCAL
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Searching for user 'spectrum@DOMAIN.LOCAL', with user search [ searchFilter: '(| (userPrincipalName=
{0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))', searchBase: 'CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAI
N.LOCAL tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Key for the principal HTTP/DC.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL not available in default key tab
                [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed
Unable to obtain password from user

DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
ERROR 4564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain password from user
; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain password from user
 [Root exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
]
        at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:182)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:285)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:119)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:138)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:791)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:194)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(LdapUserDetailsService.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:446)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:145)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
<1 - snipped ->
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.client.KerberosLdapContextSource.login(KerberosLdapContextSource.java:143)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.client.KerberosLdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(KerberosLdapContextSource.java:102)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:273)
        ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.client.KerberosLdapContextSource.login(KerberosLdapContextSource.java:139)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: After much troubleshooting, it appears to be just bad coding.  The keytab file location is supposed to be extracted into a string in afterPropertiesSet() method of SunJaasKbr5LoginConfig.  Unfortunately the method never gets called using the stock sample code so even though you pass it the keytab location in the application.yml it never gets processed properly.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. In the future it would be nice to get a bug report for such things. I went ahead and created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/issues/21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's going wrong here which is my mistake.`SunJaasKrb5LoginConfig` in `WebSecurityConfig` is not created as bean so `afterPropertiesSet()` is not called, thus causing what you just reported.

1. In `WebSecurityConfig.kerberosLdapContextSource()` call `loginConfig.afterPropertiesSet()` manually.
2. Or create `SunJaasKrb5LoginConfig` as bean in a normal spring way and let framework to call its `afterPropertiesSet()`.

This slipped from my radar because I had to use `-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/to/krb5.ini` in my tests due to my complex krb setup and I had a path to keytab file there.

I did a fix with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/commit/f354bc29f2c6558456cfc7fbfc84d0c1b6fd0606, let us know if this fixes your issue.